# Where do I find the LDAP scheme for Postifx or which alternative should I use?

Tags: postfix, ldap, openldap, schema

The howto https://www.postfix.org/LDAP_README.html describes LDAP object with

- object classes

  - `virtualaccount`
  - `ldapgroup`
  - `ldapuser`
- attributes

  - `mail`
  - `memberdn`
  - `memberaddr`
  - `maildrop`

Where do I find the LDAP schemata for those?

It does not seem to be a standard/core schema and Postfix doesn't provide an schema either.

The COSINE schema defines the attribute `mail` and the inetOrg schema uses that attribute for the object class `inetOrgPerson`. But that's it.

Do I have to define my own scheme?

Is it possible to use a well-known scheme and make Postfix use other attributes? What do you recommend?

Currently, I am considering to use the structural class `interOrgPerson`, which provides the attribute `mail`, in combination with the auxiliary class `inetLocalMailRecipient`, which provides the attribute `mailLocalAddress`. The latter could serve as an replacement for `maildrop`. But I do not see a standard way how to support mail groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a be existing Schema Files or create Custom Schema Files.

If you haven't done so yet, you may want to review the following OpenLDAP Schema Documentation.

OpenLDAP 2.6 Schema Documentation:
https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin26/schema.html

I believe that the "inetorgperson.schema" file is installed with OpenLDAP. However, if you're worried about Email Group Support, you may have to create a custom Schema File.

The following articles may help to get you started. This first article discusses creating a custom scheme similar to "inetorgperson", but some group related functionality.

https://doku.dev/tags/postfix/

https://liquidat.wordpress.com/2015/04/23/howto-ldap-schema-for-postfix/

https://kb.leuxner.net/article/mail-server-using-ldap-backend-w-postfix-dovecot/

I'll review my personal Notes/Documentation and if I find anything else that may be beneficial to you, I'll drop it, in the comments, below.